# No Value Given For One or More Required Parameters, using sub-select queries

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to execute this select query in vb.net but it throws at me the No Value Given For One or More Required Parameters error. I keep re-checking my code but cannot see what is wrong.

`SELECT` statement to pull houseno, housename, street, productname, sequenceno and quantity using the `DailyDelivery` table, where the roundID = selectedID

```
Command.CommandText = 
"SELECT customerid, 
       productid, 
       quantity, 
       (SELECT houseno 
        FROM   customer 
        WHERE  customer.customerid = dailydelivery.customerid) AS HouseNo, 
       (SELECT housename 
        FROM   customer 
        WHERE  customer.customerid = dailydelivery.customerid) AS HouseName, 
       (SELECT street 
        FROM   customer 
        WHERE  customer.customerid = dailydelivery.customerid) AS Street, 
       (SELECT sequenceno 
        FROM   customer 
        WHERE  customer.customerid = dailydelivery.customerid) AS SequenceNo, 
       (SELECT roundid 
        FROM   customer 
        WHERE  customer.customerid = dailydelivery.customerid) AS RoundID, 
       (SELECT productname 
        FROM   product 
        WHERE  product.productid = dailydelivery.productid)    AS ProductName 
FROM   dailydelivery 
WHERE  issuedate = @TodaysDate 
       AND roundid = @SelectedID 
ORDER  BY sequenceno, 
          street, 
          houseno, 
          housename"

'Add parameter for command (TodaysDate being today's date)
    `Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TodaysDate", Today.Date)`

'Add parameter for command (SelectedID being the current roundID)
    `Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedID", SelectedID)`
```

After this, command is called using a data adapter to fill a table in a dataset.

```
'Open connection to the database
dbConnection.Open()

'Set command's connection as dbconnection
Command.Connection = dbConnection

'Set the data adapter's select command as command
DataAdpt.SelectCommand = Command

'Fill ActualDelivery table in selectedDataset with the results of query, using the data adapter
DataAdpt.Fill(SelectedDataset, "ActualDelivery")

'Close connection to the database
dbConnection.Close()
```

The error is thrown on the `DataAdapt.Fill` line. I am using VB Express 2008 and Access 2013.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that Access 2013's SQL doesn't support `JOIN` - oh, [it does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197346.aspx) - you could significantly simplify this query, before anything else.

Comment: What type of command object is `Command`? Can you show the declaration/assignment for it please?

Comment: `Command` is declared in a module using, `Public Command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I am wrong but I can't test the query. 
I think you could refactor that query using JOIN

```
"SELECT d.customerid, d.productid, d.quantity, c.HouseNo, c.HouseName, " + 
"c.Street, c.SequenceNo, c.RoundID, p.ProductName " + 
"FROM (customer AS c INNER JOIN dailydelivery AS d ON c.customerid = d.customerid) " + 
"INNER JOIN product AS p ON p.productid = d.productid " + 
"WHERE  d.issuedate = @TodaysDate AND c.roundid = @SelectedID " + 
"ORDER  BY c.sequenceno,  c.street, c.houseno, c.housename"
```

Looking again at your query. Do you have a field named `roundid` on the dailydelivery table or is it the `roundid` of the customer table? As it stands now you need to have that field on the `dailydelivery` table otherwise it will be interpreted as the name of a parameter

Comment: The roundID is on the customer table at the moment

Comment: So let's change the query above and give it a try. (By the way try it in Access)

Comment: Access won't accept just `JOIN`.  You must specify whether you want `INNER`, `LEFT` or `RIGHT` for each join.  If possible, build and test your query in an Access session.  Once you have that working properly, use the same SQL in your .Net.

Comment: Ok my bad, as @HansUp says, you need to use the specifier `INNER,LEFT or RIGHT`. [Here a short tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Works in Access without using parameters (just the actual values) but throws a data type mismatch actually in VB. I'm assuming ill just need to sort out my parameters and ill be good to go?

Comment: `AddWithValue` derives the parameter datatype from the value. So, yes, probably you need to convert to the correct datatype expected by Access

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your parameters using just `?` question marks, and make sure you add your parameters to the [`Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) collection in the correct order. Or to just quote the documentation:

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an [`OleDbCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.aspx) when [`CommandType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.commandtype.aspx) is set to **Text**. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:
>
> ```
>  SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
> ```
>
> Therefore, the order in which [`OleDbParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx) objects are added to the [`OleDbParameterCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.aspx) must directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.